# Macbook 2010 Crash upon mild to heavy load

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash

My mid 2010 15" MacBook Pro crashes about 3-5 times a day.

Symptoms:

1. if I start an iMovie trailer and scroll the options (always)
2. using Chrome (sometimes)
3. if I perform too much activity right after wake up from sleep (sometimes)
4. if I preview files from finder (sometimes).
5. just about anywhere (sometimes)

What I tested:

1. happens on different OS (Leopard, Yosemite, Win7 via Bootcamp)
2. ran memtest, removed memory cards and repeated crash
3. happens on different hard-drive (old HDD, new SSD, and after clean 
   install)
4. happened more frequently on Leopard
5. usually it crashes again shortly after the first crash. a few seconds to another restart

My final guess would be either some internal component (motherboard, some data buss) OR a CPU temperature problem, but I can't read the crash log. Any idea?

Some crash reports

```
Anonymous UUID:       C69D5F4C-6D3F-C657-58A1-7781CB827543

Thu Jan 21 17:48:01 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f99e77c1b): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff8133745000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.10.25/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8118c7aca0 : 0xffffff801712ad21 
0xffffff8118c7ad20 : 0xffffff7f99e77c1b 
0xffffff8118c7ae00 : 0xffffff7f97d85b9f 
0xffffff8118c7aec0 : 0xffffff7f97e4f18e 
0xffffff8118c7af00 : 0xffffff7f97e4f1fe 
0xffffff8118c7af70 : 0xffffff7f980ce056 
0xffffff8118c7b0a0 : 0xffffff7f97e7282d 
0xffffff8118c7b0c0 : 0xffffff7f97d8c5f1 
0xffffff8118c7b170 : 0xffffff7f97d8a0fc 
0xffffff8118c7b370 : 0xffffff7f97d8ba4b 
0xffffff8118c7b440 : 0xffffff7f994577aa 
0xffffff8118c7b520 : 0xffffff7f99454a7c 
0xffffff8118c7b5a0 : 0xffffff7f99455631 
0xffffff8118c7b620 : 0xffffff7f99455e56 
0xffffff8118c7b760 : 0xffffff7f994568fb 
0xffffff8118c7b890 : 0xffffff7f99489bce 
0xffffff8118c7b8d0 : 0xffffff7f9948a923 
0xffffff8118c7b910 : 0xffffff7f9948434c 
0xffffff8118c7ba70 : 0xffffff7f99484c5c 
0xffffff8118c7bab0 : 0xffffff7f99480213 
0xffffff8118c7bae0 : 0xffffff7f994633a4 
0xffffff8118c7bb30 : 0xffffff8017700a12 
0xffffff8118c7bb60 : 0xffffff8017701609 
0xffffff8118c7bbc0 : 0xffffff80176fed83 
0xffffff8118c7bd00 : 0xffffff80171e1307 
0xffffff8118c7be10 : 0xffffff801712ef8c 
0xffffff8118c7be40 : 0xffffff80171139f3 
0xffffff8118c7be90 : 0xffffff801712429d 
0xffffff8118c7bf10 : 0xffffff801720231a 
0xffffff8118c7bfb0 : 0xffffff80172344c6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.10.25)[752C63EA-73E8-39BC-8225-3A97D0C403BF]@0xffffff7f99e69000->0xffffff7f99e7cfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.10.25)[3DC2F93F-5197-3B16-8975-0142E7A0474B]@0xffffff7f99e61000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f97c6c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f97924000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f97cde000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[65E3187E-949B-36E9-BA33-1B13ABB0581A]@0xffffff7f99e64000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f97d35000->0xffffff7f97f9efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f97924000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f97d25000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f97cde000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f97fa9000->0xffffff7f98252fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f97d35000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f97924000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[59758864-B0B8-3ED7-B4B9-DBBFAC568F35]@0xffffff7f99426000->0xffffff7f994f3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f97924000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f97d25000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f97cde000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f97d35000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x0000000016e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8017000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8016f00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1586122709308
last loaded kext at 9851010882: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.4 (addr 0xffffff7f99fea000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 104840285395: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f985b8000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.4
com.tuxera.filesystems.tufsfs.fusefs_txantfs    2012.4.17
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.4
com.avg.Antivirus.OnAccess.kext 2015.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.5
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
```

and another

```
Anonymous UUID:       C69D5F4C-6D3F-C657-58A1-7781CB827543

Thu Jan 21 14:17:47 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f8c877c1b): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff80b207b000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.10.25/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80c60e3680 : 0xffffff8009b2ad21 
0xffffff80c60e3700 : 0xffffff7f8c877c1b 
0xffffff80c60e37e0 : 0xffffff7f8a785b9f 
0xffffff80c60e38a0 : 0xffffff7f8a84f18e 
0xffffff80c60e38e0 : 0xffffff7f8a84f1fe 
0xffffff80c60e3950 : 0xffffff7f8aace056 
0xffffff80c60e3a80 : 0xffffff7f8a87282d 
0xffffff80c60e3aa0 : 0xffffff7f8a78c5f1 
0xffffff80c60e3b50 : 0xffffff7f8a78a0fc 
0xffffff80c60e3d50 : 0xffffff7f8a78b19c 
0xffffff80c60e3e30 : 0xffffff7f8a737f5e 
0xffffff80c60e3e90 : 0xffffff7f8c8479d6 
0xffffff80c60e3ee0 : 0xffffff7f8c846692 
0xffffff80c60e3f00 : 0xffffff8009b5d6d9 
0xffffff80c60e3fb0 : 0xffffff8009c116e7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.10.25)[752C63EA-73E8-39BC-8225-3A97D0C403BF]@0xffffff7f8c869000->0xffffff7f8c87cfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.10.25)[3DC2F93F-5197-3B16-8975-0142E7A0474B]@0xffffff7f8c861000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f8a66c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f8a324000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f8a6de000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[65E3187E-949B-36E9-BA33-1B13ABB0581A]@0xffffff7f8c864000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8a735000->0xffffff7f8a99efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f8a324000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f8a725000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f8a6de000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f8a9a9000->0xffffff7f8ac52fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8a735000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f8a324000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(110.19.6)[993A6073-348D-388A-8BE5-F0EA14E61D67]@0xffffff7f8c844000->0xffffff7f8c857fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f8a324000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(5.9.1d7)[593924B4-A956-3CA5-9610-448D50D96947]@0xffffff7f8b1e3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f8a725000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f8a6de000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.10.25)[DFDCFB7E-74E4-397E-AA6F-6ECFC41D5649]@0xffffff7f8c83d000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009900000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 124358475101
last loaded kext at 46648416217: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8ac78000, size 69632)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.4
com.tuxera.filesystems.tufsfs.fusefs_txantfs    2012.4.17
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.4
com.avg.Antivirus.OnAccess.kext 2015.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.5
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIPassThrough   1.0.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
```

Comment: Those errors point to the GPU (graphics processing unit.) If this MBP was part of the pool of known defective MBPs with bad GPUs, the free repair window has come & gone: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554 .

Comment: will reducing the load of the GPU help stabalize the system? is that even possible?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this model of MBP and, like you, sometimes experience kernel panics when a program tries to use the discrete NVIDIA GPU, rather than the integrated Intel graphics chipset. There is a program called gfxCardStatus (https://gfx.io) which gives the user some control over whether the integrated or discrete graphics are being used. It does not work perfectly - sometimes the discrete GPU will be activated even when I don't want it to, and I have to turn it back off quickly - but you may find it useful.

For some applications which would otherwise use the discrete GPU, you can allow them to stay with integrated graphics by adding a boolean variable `NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching` with value `true` to their `Info.plist`, using the following Terminal command: [(link)](http://zacwe.st/blog/rdio-discrete-card/)

```
defaults write <path to app>/Contents/Info.plist NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching -bool YES
```

or you can add this setting to the plist [by hand](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/make-x11-applications-use-the-integrated-gpu.1321711/).

Finally, you might want to try taking your machine to an Apple Store. Even though the free repair program has officially ended, they may still do the repair (logic board replacement) without charge if you ask.

Update:
Any *official* repair *from Apple* is not possible anymore: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554 The machine is now of vintage status.

Comment: All great info from @d. Ray. Just wanted to confirm that the Apple Store will still do the logic board replacement - I had it done for this very problem. It's a $300 flat rate repair IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem from Apple. I made a program to fix this issue. You can check it out here, it's free and open-source : https://github.com/julian-poidevin/MBPMid2010_GPUFix/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Since the accepted answer here is not as good as this stub-like answer by Poidevin, people landing here should also look at an expanded version here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285801/251859