# MacBook Pro 15'' (Mid 2010) regularly crashes for unknown reason

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro suddenly began crashing regularly, and I can't tell why.

**Panic report:**

```
Anonymous UUID:       5268AAE1-4401-D38B-9AD1-A8554209B5A3

Tue Jul 26 20:10:11 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7f90241bd5): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff9129e7c000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.12.8/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91191a2ac0 : 0xffffff800d0dab52 
0xffffff91191a2b40 : 0xffffff7f90241bd5 
0xffffff91191a2c20 : 0xffffff7f8dd84fa4 
0xffffff91191a2ce0 : 0xffffff7f8de51add 
0xffffff91191a2d20 : 0xffffff7f8de51b48 
0xffffff91191a2da0 : 0xffffff7f8e0d6a23 
0xffffff91191a2f10 : 0xffffff7f8de75b79 
0xffffff91191a2f30 : 0xffffff7f8dd8bcfd 
0xffffff91191a2fe0 : 0xffffff7f8dd89690 
0xffffff91191a31e0 : 0xffffff7f8dd8b141 
0xffffff91191a32b0 : 0xffffff7f8f740985 
0xffffff91191a3400 : 0xffffff7f8f73564f 
0xffffff91191a3750 : 0xffffff7f8f6e93e2 
0xffffff91191a3790 : 0xffffff7f8f73a3a5 
0xffffff91191a3820 : 0xffffff7f8f722201 
0xffffff91191a3880 : 0xffffff7f8f722b22 
0xffffff91191a38d0 : 0xffffff7f8f722ffd 
0xffffff91191a3940 : 0xffffff7f8f7236f1 
0xffffff91191a3980 : 0xffffff7f8f6f0408 
0xffffff91191a3b00 : 0xffffff7f8f6eef63 
0xffffff91191a3b50 : 0xffffff800d6e1586 
0xffffff91191a3b80 : 0xffffff800d6e2e50 
0xffffff91191a3be0 : 0xffffff800d6dfed7 
0xffffff91191a3d20 : 0xffffff800d197f90 
0xffffff91191a3e30 : 0xffffff800d0df2c3 
0xffffff91191a3e60 : 0xffffff800d0c28f8 
0xffffff91191a3ea0 : 0xffffff800d0d26a5 
0xffffff91191a3f10 : 0xffffff800d1b8eca 
0xffffff91191a3fb0 : 0xffffff800d1ecd86 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.12.8)[3186B630-FFF4-32C9-BAB9-DCD0C9DB6BA2]@0xffffff7f90233000->0xffffff7f90246fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.12.8)[C57F5F56-2229-365F-9765-F24AA4687584]@0xffffff7f9022b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f8dbb3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7f8d92c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f8dcd7000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[C49819CE-729A-36B2-9AC1-744A43DC236F]@0xffffff7f9022e000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f8dd2e000->0xffffff7f8dfa3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7f8d92c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[4EB2843C-C821-3AD0-B333-575FD6ED6FB1]@0xffffff7f8dd1e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f8dcd7000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[56199CA6-3C8D-3EBB-B5EF-7B1B4678ACF9]@0xffffff7f8dfae000->0xffffff7f8e25bfff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f8dd2e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7f8d92c000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[32600385-A687-3621-A12E-497D690B623A]@0xffffff7f8f6dd000->0xffffff7f8f7a8fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7f8d92c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[4EB2843C-C821-3AD0-B333-575FD6ED6FB1]@0xffffff7f8dd1e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f8dcd7000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f8dd2e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
15G31

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B5AA8E3E-65B6-3D0E-867B-8DCCF81E536C
Kernel slide:     0x000000000ce00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800cf00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 97856144426789
last loaded kext at 95958732570054: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f903a9000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 96404324672468: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff7f903a9000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.nke.rvi   2.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.8
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B11, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533641465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533641465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS256B, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

I recently brought it in for service. A full hardware diagnostics was run, no faults detected.

Any ideas what might be wrong and how I can try to fix it?

**Update (26.07.16):**

I have now reset the [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). I'll post an update if it works or if the issue still persists.

**Update (27.07.16):**

Nope. Resetting NVRAM and SMC didn't help. The same crash still occurs.

Comment: The first line in the panic report gives a strong clue - *GPU Panic*.  Chances are, your graphic chip is failing.  You can run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.   to do some further diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks, Allan - I'll try running AHT and see if it reports anything wonky. What's odd is that I had it serviced by Apple's authorised service centre in Norway two weeks ago and they couldn't find any hardware problems—Maybe they missed something.

Comment: It may be intermittent.  I've had laptop GPUs fail and then work fine for weeks only to fail again.  You may have to run AHT several times if it is intermittent.

Comment: When I try running AHT by holding down the D-key when powering on with the power chord connected, I only the grey screen for a long time (1-2 minutes) and then the user login icons appear as normally. For some reason, I can't get it to start the AHT.

Comment: It's possible that your MBP came with AHT on Disk 2 of the installer disk.  Do you still have it?

Comment: Ah, crap—Probably not, because I moved several times internationally and probably tossed it out or lost it. But as far as I can tell from Apple's info page, AHT should run over the Internet if it doesn't exist on the hard drive—I will try that next to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem from Apple. I made a program to fix this issue. You can check it out here, it's free and open-source: https://github.com/julian-poidevin/MBPMid2010_GPUFix/

Gist of the above page to give more background to the solution:

MBPMid2010_GPUFix is an utility program that allows to fix MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) intermittent black screen or loss of video. The algorithm is based on a solution provided by user fabioroberto on MacRumors forums.

The bug is in hardware: it's due to a bad type choice on a decoupling capacitor used on GPU motherboard part [image]

It has been detected that the problem happens every time that G-State change between 2 to 0.

G-States go from 0 to 3, are related to the thresholds inside AppleGraphicsPowerManagement.kext, like this:

G-state 0 (maximum speed)
G-state 3 (lowest speed).
The problem can be 'solved' by keeping it always at G-State 2 (medium speed).
The linked program automates this task.

Although: as stated that the bug is manifest in hardware, the best fix is to replace this tiny and cheap component. 
The software workaround lowers the performance of the chip.
The hardware fix will restore the machine to advertised specs.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that seems to be working in my case.

Go to *Energy Saver* (in *System Preferences*) and disable *Automatic graphics switching*.

This will affect performance, of course, but I haven't experienced any crashes since I did this.